# Poppler Installation on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, poppler, pdf2image, poppler-utils

I am trying to convert pdf to image using pdf2image module on Google Colab.
I have downloaded the latest version of poppler and also installed poppler-utils.
In convert_from_path() , I mentioned the correct path to poppler's bin directory, still I'm getting FileNotFoundError and PDFInfoNotInstalled Error.

Refer to the attached Screenshot for more clarity.
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIAa8.jpg)

Comment: How have you installed poppler? What is your poppler bin directory. Please provide the stacktrace of the error as text and not a screenshot. Also provide code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Google colab is running a Ubuntu operating system, you can discover that by running the `uname -a` command.

If [you build poppler](https://askubuntu.com/a/1368126/1635322), the pdf* binaries are installed in `/usr/bin` and pdf2image can resolve them automatically.

Discover the operating system name.

```bash
!uname -a;
```

```
Linux d9b9a62155f2 5.10.133+ #1 SMP Fri Aug 26 08:44:51 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bash
!cat requirements.txt
```

```
pdf2image
```

Install python dependencies

```bash
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Install some dependencies for building poppler

```bash
!apt update
!apt-get install libnss3 libnss3-dev
!apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev
!apt-get install cmake libblkid-dev e2fslibs-dev libboost-all-dev libaudit-dev
```

Download and extract poppler source code.

```bash
!wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-21.09.0.tar.xz;
!tar -xvf poppler-21.09.0.tar.xz;
```

Compile and install poppler.

```bash
!mkdir -p poppler-21.09.0/build && \
cd poppler-21.09.0 && \
cmake  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release   \
       -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr  \
       -DTESTDATADIR=$PWD/testfiles \
       -DENABLE_UNSTABLE_API_ABI_HEADERS=ON && \
make && \
make install
```

Work with the PDF file

```py
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes

images = convert_from_path('sample.pdf', poppler_path='/usr/bin/')
```

Answer (score 0):

For colab, try installing the below commands and try convert_from_path

```
#Libraries to be installed
!sudo apt-get update
!apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Then try
`pages = convert_from_path('filename', 500)`

It should work.

I recommend this answer as it worked for me best than other answers. If it doesn't work even after installing the library, then try restarting the kernel and run the code convert_from_path. It should work now.