# Installing Poppler in Google Colab for deepdoctection

Tags: python, pdf, google-colaboratory, ocr, poppler

I want to run an example code from https://github.com/deepdoctection/deepdoctection readme in Colab:

```
import deepdoctection as dd
from IPython.core.display import HTML
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

analyzer = dd.get_dd_analyzer()  # instantiate the built-in analyzer similar to the Hugging Face space demo

df = analyzer.analyze(path = "/path/to/your/doc.pdf")  # setting up pipeline
df.reset_state()                 # Trigger some initialization

doc = iter(df)
page = next(doc) 

image = page.viz()
plt.figure(figsize = (25,17))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(image)
```

But I get this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/deepdoctection/utils/pdf_utils.py in _input_to_cli_str(input_file_name, output_file_name, dpi, size)
    160         command = "pdftocairo"
    161     else:
--> 162         raise PopplerNotFound("Poppler not found. Please install or add to your PATH.")
    163 
    164     if platform.system() == "Windows":

PopplerNotFound: Poppler not found. Please install or add to your PATH.
```

I have tried options from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823700/poppler-installation-on-google-colab) and some others and they don't change anything.